# Kivy camera_screen not showing and giving graphic fbo error 'invalid frustrum', what's the solution?

Tags: python, camera, kivy

I created a Kivy Home.py application that has BottomNavigation in the screen and it has 3 buttons, in the middle is camera. I already have the screen for it, but when I click the button, The camera_screen.py doesn't show, and it always show this fbo graphics error:

```
 ValueError: invalid frustrum
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.fbo.Fbo.create_fbo'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\graphics\transformation.pyx", line 301, in kivy.graphics.transformation.Matrix.view_clip
 ValueError: invalid frustrum
```

Can you guys have remedy for this? Thanks.

**Home.py BottomNav:**

```
kv='''

MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen 2'
                text: 'Camera'
                icon: 'camera'
                # badge_icon: "numeric-5"
                on_tab_release: root.go_to_cam_screen

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Camera'
                    halign: 'center' 
                    md_bg_color: 0.941, 0.886, 0.835, 1                  #F0E2D5
'''

class Home(Screen):
    def go_to_diagnose_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = "diagnose_screen"
    
    def go_to_notepad_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = "notepad_screen"

    def go_to_cam_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = "cam_screen"

    def go_to_profile_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = "profile_screen"
```

**camera_screen.py:
**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time
from kivy.graphics import Fbo
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (350,600)

Builder.load_string('''
<CameraScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width, root.height
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        Image:
            id: camera_preview
            texture: root.fbo.texture if root.fbo else None
            size_hint_y: 0.8
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Play'
            on_press: root.toggle_camera()
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Capture'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_press: root.capture()
''')


class CameraScreen(Screen):
    fbo = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CameraScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fbo = Fbo(size=Window.size, with_stencilbuffer=True)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.fbo.add(self.ids.camera_preview.canvas)

    def on_leave(self):
        self.fbo.remove(self.ids.camera_preview.canvas)

    def toggle_camera(self):
        camera = self.ids.camera
        camera.play = not camera.play

    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids.camera
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")
```

I tried importing kivy.graphics Fbo and added some flag in its camera_screen class, and it still doesn''t work.